# Whats the right way to test an array of model values in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec2

I've yet to get my head around the rspec way of writing tests, but would appreciate some help in understanding what I've done wrong with this test.

```
describe Source do

  describe "Upcase name" do
     names = {'bob' => 'Bob',
            'edward jones' => 'Edward Jones'
        'Edward jones' => 'Edward Jones'}

     names.each do |name,expect|
       before { @source = Source.create(name: name) }
       after { @source.destroy! }

       it "source #{name} should be #{expect}" do
         subject { @source }
         @source.name.should == expect

         let!(:find) do 
           Source.find_by_proper_name(expect)
         end
         it "should find" do
           should == find
         end
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

I have a unique constraint on the name column of the source model.

Every iteration of the test comes back as a failure due to unique violation. (even though I thought it would create only one model per iteration.

If I take out the middle of the three so all names are unique if it creates all at once - then the tests fail because @source is equal to the last value in all tests.

Essentially I want a DRY way to write the tests

```
Source.create(name: "bob").name.should == "Bob"
Source.create(name: "edward jones").name.should == "Edward Jones"
Source.create(name: "Edward jones").name.should == "Edward Jones"
```

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are mixing a lot of stuff in there...

first things first:

- do not nest `it`
- do not use `let` in `it` they belong in `context`
- do not iterate `it`s iterate in the `it`
- do not cleanup the db yourself, use database cleaner or transactional fixtures or something like that

have a look at how i do spec like these, maybe this helps you somehow: https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby/blob/master/spec/models/user_spec.rb#L15